# sync 10 asynctask serially one after another in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have 10 asynctask and I would like to sync all of them one after another along with null check.If sqlite_cursor_array has null value then it should execute next asynctask or else wait for the current asynctask to finish so technically only one asynctask will be executed at a given time.I have tried to make it work wit the code below .But I am not sure if it wait for one asynctask to finsih then get to another one.Its not syncing properly and I dont know if I am doing it right ? Thanks

```
          async1 async1_test = new async1();
            async1_test.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR );

                            if(async1_test.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
                                ///
                        async2 async2_test = new async2(Sync.this,getjsonarray_sqlite1);
                        async2_test.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR );
                        if(async2_test.getStatus() ==AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){

                 async3 async3_test = new async3(Sync.this,getjsonarray_sqlite2);
                    async3_test.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR );
                    if(async3_test.getStatus() ==AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){

                     /// so on for another 10 asynctask
                     }

                 }
```

Comment: just use 1 (one) async task for this ... there is no need to use more then 1 if you need to run 'em "in a row"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a framework. The [Bolts](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android) library has several ways to chain Tasks that is pretty nice IMO. One of its advantages is reducing the amount of indentation, and you can handle errors in a clean way.

Answer (score 0):

In onPostExecute, check if your Asynchronous Task has finished

```
if(async1_test.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
```

If true, reinitialize the object and start the Async Task again.

Keep this thing mind, Android only lets one object  of Aysnc Task to execute once so if you want to execute it again, use a new object

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Serial Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR) for handling such kind of situation.

```
new AsynTask1().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_Executor,params);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Execute first AsyncTask then execute the second AsysncTask in the onPostExecute method of the first AsyncTask and so on.

```
new FirstAsyncTask().execute();

private class FirstAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     //do something
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     new SecondAsyncTask().execute();
 }
}

private class SecondAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     //do something
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    new ThirdAsyncTask().execute();
 }
}
```

and so on.....

Comment: I  tried that but it does not work properly .Also if its null I have no idea how it can go to 3rd or 4th asynctask..Basically any array can be null but all asynctask have to run in any case coz any table might be updated.Is there a queue or something to fix this >

Comment: Tried this but I did not get the required result.Few tables were missing.